# Constructing a predictive scoring system for a binary output

Tags: regression, binary, scoring

I have a system that has several continuous variables as inputs. The output is a binary pass/fail type. The relationship between the continuous variables and the changes of a "pass" is that there is an optimal value within some range (perhaps the curve looks parabolic). I want to be able to calculate a probability of achieving a "pass" based on a given set of data for each continuous variable, how should I approach this? Any readily available commercial packages?

Comment: `want to be able to calculate a probability of achieving a "pass" based on a given set of data for each continuous variable` Could you please elaborate on what you mean? One of the advantages of regression and machine learning is considering multiple variables at once, yet you seem not to want to do that. Have I misinterpreted your remark?